# Can I use sites.php to resolve subdomain on my multi-site installation?

Tags: multi-sites

I have a Drupal multi-site setup on Ubuntu.

One of the multi-sites is **cyber.site.edu**.

Our requirement is to have another virtul host named **cyber1.site.edu**.

cyber1.site.edu should also resolve to cyber.site.edu

Can I use example.sites.php? I read the documentation at [this link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!example.sites.php/7) but it is not clear to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will do most of your set up with your server: Apache, IIS, etc. Your settings.php file will be in your site specific folder i.e. `sites/cyber1.site.edu/settings.php` Here you will define your db etc.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes your multi-site structure is as follows:

```
sites/site.edu  
sites/cyber.site.edu
```

Let's start at the top by addressing a few key things:

#### 1. Is there a DNS entry for your subdomain?

When working locally, you should add the subdomain to your hosts file.

***Hint:** If browsing to cyber1.site.edu generates "This webpage is not available", the answer is no.*

Help: [(AskUbuntu) Setting up subdomain on Ubuntu server](https://askubuntu.com/a/463623)

#### 2. Have your Virtual Hosts been properly configured?

You need to inform Apache how to pass the correct domains to Drupal.

***Hint:** If browsing to cyber1.site.edu generates a Drupal site installation page, the answer is no.*

Help: [How To Enable Multiple Sites on a Drupal Installation On Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-multiple-sites-on-a-drupal-installation-on-ubuntu-12-04)

#### 3. Do you have a folder in *sites/* bearing the actual hostname, including the subdomain?

In this case, we already know the answer is no. If the answer were yes and you had a folder in *sites/* named *cyber1.site.edu* then Drupal would be able to auto-discover it in the usual way. Since you do not, we need to tell Drupal what to do.

This is where *sites.php* comes in handy:

---

#### Setting up sites.php

From the docs in *sites/example.sites.php*:

> This file allows you to define a set of aliases that map hostnames and
> pathnames to configuration directories. These aliases are loaded prior
> to scanning for directories, and they are exempt from the normal
> discovery rules. (...)
>
> To use this file, copy and rename it such that its path plus filename is 'sites/sites.php'.

Add this line to the end of the file and save.

```
$sites['cyber1.site.edu'] = 'cyber.site.edu';
```